# How to implement a permissions system like highrise or facebook

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Hey I am looking to implement a permissions system like in [highrise](http://productblog.37signals.com/products/2010/03/new-in-highrise-bulk-tagging-permissions-delete-and-more.html) or facebook.

The issue with such an problem is that permissions have to defined on a instance of the object(visibility). Off the top of my head i can think of saving user_ids, or group_ids in a hash for every record. Is that the best way to do it?

I am using mongodb so that should make it easier. Although we can switch to sql also (highrise probably does it with sql).

Edit: I ended up writing a gem that works with mongoid, you can read more about it [here](http://abhishiv.tumblr.com/post/3704204783/document-level-permissions-with-permissible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Abhishiv: given this task, I would implement some form of convention for setting access by field.

Given an object like the following:

```
{
  name : "me",
  user : "me01234",
  salary : "100",
  address : "123 Nowhere drive"
}
```

I would add permissions by doing something like this:

```
{
  name : "me",
  user : "me01234",
  salary : "100",
  address : "123 Nowhere drive"
  p_salary : [ 'g/accounting', 'g/management', 'u/owner' ]
  p_address : [ 'g/accounting', 'g/hr', 'u/me' ]
}
```

With conventions like this, you can maintain document-level access permissions. And it's pretty easy to see how to program such a thing.

Now typically you want access permissions on both the object and the collection itself. This keeps the whole process much more DRY. For such a thing, I would simply build a "permissions" collection that contains default permissions for each other collection in the DB.

Off the top of my head, I don't know of any framework that does this "out of the box". I would look at Mongoid and MongoMapper and see if this type of detail isn't appropriate for a plug-in.

Comment: this seems the way to go. It also means we'll have to go with mongo because as far as i know there's no way to query hashes in sql. Or maybe a mix of sql and mongo. Thanks for you reply. I'll consider turning this into a plugin for mongoid.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Cancan: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have used cancan before, but its implementation differs. I still need a way to store permissions about an instance(row/object) in the database. At that point i can think of using cancan on top of that. – Asaxena 7 secs ago edit

Comment: +1 for cancan. maybe not suitable here, but it's the awesomeness of all

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [declarative authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization)?

Comment: yes, but the same issue. I need a way to store visibilty of an instance in a column.